# supervisorctl -c ../../etc/xxx.conf update has a error xmlrpclib.Fault

Tags: python-2.7, supervisord, xmlrpclib

when supervisorctl update, prompt the CANT_REREAD: could not find config file ../../etc/xxx.conf'>: file: /data/service/python/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py line: 793